# how to link the own opencv libray with out default library with cpp program

Tags: c++

I have created my own OpenCV library that i had removed the files and functions which are not used in my application and written the makefile according to my changes.
Changes like all the opencv libraries  like core,imgproc,cuda,calib3d,imgcodecs,video,videoio,ml etc are compresseed into only one shared object(.so) file.
I have also included my application source files with that the opencv modules source files and finally generated the single library  i want to call my source api's from my side.
I want to call my source api's which are inlcuded in that single library file,but when i'm calling to my api's from my test c++ application,it throws linking errors......
Errors like : Testapp.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `Initialize' and the command i used to call my api's was   g++ -o a Testapp.cpp -L. -lopencv_innovision

Comment: Try to link with libsupc++

Comment: can u suggest me how to use this

Comment: [Check this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.what_is_libsupcxx) so if you sure you have no iostreams or vectors/maps/string etc you can use this subset library by adding `-lsupc++` to linker.

Comment: But i am using vectors,iostreams etc in my library.

Comment: if possible ,can you suggest me another way